# Can figures float to another .tex file in a fragmented system

Tags: floats

This question is more about how LaTeX works, than any concrete example, thus there is no MWE, and it's purely hypothetical. If this is not allowed, please tell me, I will delete the question, I'm just curious about this.

Say I have a system like the following:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\include{1}
\include{2}
\include{3}
\include{4}
\end{document}
```

In each tex tile there is a chapter

then in `1.tex` there is a lot of figures.

Here's the question:

Is it possible for the figures in `1.tex` to float into one of the other chapters in another file?

If there were not chapters in the other files, would the figures then be able to float into the content of another file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general a`\chapter` effectively starts with a `\clearpage` which will print out any preceding floats. `\include` also uses `\clearpage`. So for your MWE the answer is NO.

If instead you were to use `\input` (which does not `\clearpage`) instead of `\include` and not `\chapter` but rather `\section` (which does not `\clearpage`) then floats can migrate through the document.

Answer (score 6):

`\include` does `\clearpage`, so no, all figures from `1.tex` will be printed before `2.tex` starts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I thound @Peter Wilson's answer more informative.